# Jupyter Notebook: Autocomplete has too many suggestions

Tags: python, autocomplete, jupyter, jedi

When using autocomplete in Jupyter Notebooks it is super nice that you can use autocomplete out of the box, but the autocomplete makes too many suggestions that are not relevant. E.g. when autocompleting inside a function, then I only want relevant parameters to be autocompleted, not 60 random python values.

People have suggested using `%config Completer.use_jedi = True`, but that turns everything off and is even worse.

Comment: My autocomplete works in jupyter notebooks, but I have the same problem as you in iPython terminals - where it suggests every inbuilt function, variable and error type as an autocomplete option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing nbextension for suggestions in jupyter notebook.
for more info plz [Click here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)